# Gratis Windows 11 software to create a Disk.img file from a disk

Tags: hard-disk, image, disk-image

What well-reviewed Windows 11 software successfully creates a .img file from a disk for no cost? I already have many softwares that create their own proprietary image files in Windows, but not a Disk.img file. Linux Gnome Disks creates Disk.img files, but that is not in Windows. I am asking for free solutions, not Cost or Trial software. I am only asking for software that has 1 good review on a popular website.

Examples of softwares that do not meet these criteria: UltraISO, Backupper, PowerISO, DiskGenius, WinCDEmu.

Please reply with a link to the review of a Windows 11 software successfully creates a Disk.img file for no cost, thank you.

Comment: Hello, what do you exactly mean by "disk.img"? Isn't Windows in-built feature enough here?